# Show that the operation x is not distributive over +

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I tried doing this question but from what I gather, it is distributive. What am I doing wrong? This is what I've done so far for the question:

[image]

P.S: the binary operations are not regular multiplication and addition, I specify them in the photo.

Comment: You're computing $[(a,b)\otimes(c,d)]\oplus[(a,b)\otimes(e,f)]$ -- but where is your computation of $(a,b)\otimes[(c,d)\oplus(e,f)]$? That just dangles at the top of your work without ever being computed.

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! Please write out your question using MathJax and remove the image. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for reference.

Comment: @HenningMakholm right that makes sense, Idk how I wasn't able to look at the question like that, I think that fact that it's a mapping from R^2 x R^2 -> R^2 is what was confusing me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: I don't know whether you noticed, but consider how similar your operations are to addition and multiplication on fractions (what is $\frac ab+\frac cd$?) It just looks like you aren't allowed to simplify. Should make the rules much easier to remember and work with.

Also, if you're supposed to *disprove* distributivity, you don't have to use $a,b,c,d,e,f$. It's enough to find just *one set* of specific numbers where it doesn't work. That will probably also help you focus your attention where it should be, namely on the overarching logic, not on the rote calculations.

Comment: Thanks, also what @HenningMakholm said helped me out as well!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the other order? Pay particular attention to the second coordinate.